# Is image registration necessary among temporal Landsat images?

Tags: raster, remote-sensing, landsat, digital-image-processing, coregistration

I am working on a project comparing each pixel every 4 years for the same AOI from Landsat Images (1986-2017). It involves with Landsat 5, 7 and 8 images. Do I need to perform image registration as image preparation? I am using only RGB and NIR bands all data has the same spatial resolution (30 m). I am using higher level data (level 2). Can somebody explain why it is necessary or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Collection 1](https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-collections) is not necessary:

> In 2016, the USGS reorganized the Landsat archive into a tiered
>   collection. This structure ensures that Landsat Level-1 products
>   provide a consistent archive of known data quality to support
>   time-series analyses and data “stacking”, while controlling continuous
>   improvement of the archive and access to all data as they are
>   acquired.

So use Collection 1 Level-2 scenes:

[image]

Comment: Why would you use Level-2 instead of Level-1? Aren't they scenes with larger uncertainties, or did I misinterpret that? Also, @OguzSariyildiz you need to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @Jon I agree, but is part of the question -*I am using higher level data (level 2)*-

Comment: @Jon 2 Level-2 images are corrected atmospherically (or surface reflectance). It helps with accuracy of the values in temporal vegetation analysis (NDVI). Thank you for your comments and info!

Comment: @OguzSariyildiz for NDVI times series, I would prefer to use a radiometric normalization using invariant pixels over NDVI TOA values

Comment: @aldo_tapia Why do you think radiometric normalization using invariant pixels better than NDVI TOA values?

Comment: @OguzSariyildiz with it and for Landsat times series, you can compare different sensors (TM, ETM+,OLI). You can also take NDVI TOA an apply a normalization process. Try stacking a period NDVI BOA for ETM+ and OLI and plot a time series (if is a bare soil, better), you will see why you need to normalize Landsat series

Comment: @aldo_tapia is there resource or tutorial explaining radiometric normalization using invariant pixel that you know? Thank you!

Comment: @OguzSariyildiz Check https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bf6b/815d7577ba5a9b5d8fe38286916cb1227d2c.pdf The procedure is to select pseudo-invariant pixels (recommended a 3x3 selection per site) and apply a linear regression. When I use this method, I search bare soil and high-vegetation (excluding crops) pixels to do regresion between master and slave scenes

Comment: @OguzSariyildiz also, check this great article https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0a0f/21d33163519eee054b717575bb14f3649dfd.pdf